# Summarize and paste values in second line of same row

Tags: r, summarize

I am trying to summarise the rows and paste the values in the second line but in the same row. I tried with following code but not getting the result. Can anyone help me

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("xyz","xyz"), b = c("C1 : 2", "C2 : 3"), c = c(2,2))
df1 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(years = cat(paste(b), sep="\n"))
C1 : 2
C2 : 3
```

Expected output

```
    a     years 
  xyz    C1 : 2 
         C2 : 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another potential solution is to remove the values in the `a` column that you don't want, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("xyz","xyz"), b = c("C1 : 2", "C2 : 3"), c = c(2,2))
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(years = b)

df2[2,1] <- ""
as.data.frame(df2)
#    a  years
#1 xyz C1 : 2
#2     C2 : 3
```

Comment: Almost. But again there are 2 rows here :) Can we make only 1 row?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this with `gt` package -

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(years = paste(b, collapse ="<br>"))
gt(df2) %>% fmt_markdown(columns = years)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried but getting this error ````Warning: Error in fmt_markdown: unused argument ````

Comment: That's strange. I don't get any such error. Have you loaded `gt` library ? Try with `gt::gt(df2) %>% gt::fmt_markdown(columns = years)`